# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't copy app server descriptor and static web files to its temporary folder on debug

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, intellij-idea

Do you guys know why IntelliJ IDEA doesn't copy app server descriptor files to temporary folder on debug ?

I have gae+gwt project. I created gwt debug configuration that uses dev google app server as server.

When I launch debug session it fails with following error:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44527', transport: 'socket'
Initializing App Engine server
Apr 18, 2012 11:35:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Apr 18, 2012 11:35:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\Users\root\.IntelliJIdea11\system\gwt\courierapp.courierapp23c0d1f4\Server.3565aa46\run\www\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate C:\Users\root\.IntelliJIdea11\system\gwt\courierapp.courierapp23c0d1f4\Server.3565aa46\run\www\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:108)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:66)
```

And indeed neither `appengine-web.xml` nor `web.xml` are present in `C:\Users\root\.IntelliJIdea11\system\gwt\courierapp.courierapp23c0d1f4\Server.3565aa46\run\www\WEB-INF`. None of my htmls or other statis files are copied either.

If I copy them manually everything works fine.

So basically IDEA only copies java classes and depending jars.

Here is how my debug configuration looks like: [i39.tinypic.com/nwzuvc.jpg](http://i39.tinypic.com/nwzuvc.jpg)

I using IDEA 117.216

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out :) This mystery was bugging me for months!

I noticed this problem came up after I recreated all modules and project from sources.

The problem was that Target Web Faced wasn't set in GWT module.

[image]

**Artifact is not necessary to make it work.**

Comment: @Caio Without the GWT module, after following IntelliJ online help for creating an App Engine app, in IntelliJ IDEA 2016 Ultimate, I had to 2 additional steps:  1) In settings / Artifacts, make sure the "Build on Make" checkbox was selected and then 2) in the "Output Layout" tab, select the "WEB-INF" node, click on the plus icon and add 'appengine-web.xml' and 'web.xml'.  Then you should be able to click the run icon (green triangle) and see your app build, the development app server startup, and be automatically thrown into your default web browser and pointed to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

1. Please show us the screen capture of your artifacts. Open "Project Structure" window, then select "Artifacts" from left pane.
2. Sometimes deleting cache and rebuilding the project resolve IDEA's weird behavior. Try clearing cache then build & debug.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in Target Web Faced. I had no idea !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bjenkins01's comment on another answer I solved exactly this problem by checking the **Build on make** checkbox in the *Project Structure/Artifacts* tab.